# Finding variable values to make equations behave like boolean gate

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I came across following problem:

> Consider the following simple perceptron, for which the inputs are the always $1$ feature and two binary features $x_1 ∈ \{0, 1\}$ and $x_2 ∈ \{0, 1\}$. The output $y ∈ \{0, 1\}$.
> $$y=\begin{cases}
> 1,  & \text{if $w_0+w_1.x_1+w_2.x_2>0$ } \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$
> Choose all the correct option below that the weights $w_0,w_1,w_2$ should satisfy such that $y=(x_1 \text{ AND } x_2 )$.
> **(A)** $w_0>0$      **(b)** $w_0≤0$   **(c)** $w_1>0$        **(d)** $w_2>0$

I tried to solve the problem and came up with following:

> [image]
>
> (Eqn# stands for Equation# in above table)
> Eqn#4 $= w_0≤0$  (Option B)
> Eqn#2 $→w_0≤-w_1$    (Eqn#5)
> Eqn#3 $→w_0≤-w_2$    (Eqn#6)
> Eqn#1 $→ 0>-w_1-w_2-w_0$
> $→ 0>-w_1+(non-ve)$    … from Eqn#3
> $→ -(non-ve)>-w_1$
> $→ -ve>-w_1$
> $→ w_1>0$ (Option C)
> Similarly from Equation 4 and 2, it can be proven that $w_2>0$ (Option D)

But I feel something is wrong with above. I feel option B contradicts with both option C and option D. For example, option C and Eqn#5 makes $w_0=0$ impossible which is allowed by option B. Where did I made mistake? I feel its incorrect to directly conclude $w_0\leq 0$ from Eqn#4 and "stop". What I mean is that I have to continuously keep checking if all facts that I conclude lead to desired effect "together". For example, once I got that option (c) is correct, I have to combine Option C fact with Eqn#4 fact to conclude that $w_0<0$. So finding solution to such problems is kind of continuous process till we get all equations which satisfy each other and target goal (AND gate here). **Q1.** Am I correct with this? Or I am unnecessarily making things difficult and there is simpler and more importantly "straight forward" way (not involving continuously checking if all equations satisfy each other) to find such solutions?

**Q2.** This does also mean that Option B should have $<$ instead of $\leq$. Am I correct with this too?

**PS:**

After getting confused like me, some of my friends have started saying it should be $\geq$ instead of $\gt$:

$$y=\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $w_0+w_1.x_1+w_2.x_2\color{red}{\geq}0$ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

But I dont feel so as I can still find correct answer with given problem with conclusion that option B should have $<$ instead of $\leq$. Also I dont feel its correct for a function to interpret $0$ as $True$. **Q3.** Am I correct with this too? (problem doesnt need correction, but option B)

Answer (score 0):

You can only have $w_0 < 0$. If $w_0 = 0$, then eq 1,2,3 imply that
$$ 0 < w_{1,2} \leq 0 $$
which is a contradiction. Hence option b) is incorrect.